# Objective-C ad UIControlEventTouchUpInside event to class

Tags: ios

I understand that it is possible to add a UIControlEventTouchUpInside event to a specific object, but how could I go about adding this event to an entire class?

I have created objects with the class ElementButton, and I don't want to go through and add the event for each individual object, as that would result in a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the all the ElementButtons in an array and go through them in a `for loop`:

```
for (ElementButton *yourButton in myArray) {
    [yourButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

To get all the ElementButtons do:

```
for (ElementButton *button in [self.view subviews]) {
     if(!yourArray) yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     [yourArray addObject:button];
}
```

Comment: This solution would work best since having an array of all the objects would be very helpful later. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is iOS's implementation of something called the *target-action pattern*. Target-action is only available for subclasses of UIControl, so unless your `ElementButton` is a UIControl subclass, you cannot use UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

If it is in fact a UIControl subclass, you shouldn't need to do any extra work, other than registering for UIControlEventTouchUpInside for each object:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonTapped:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I think this, adding the action method for each button individually, is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, I would rather have one method set in ElementButton.m that took care of all the objects. There's 118 of them, and it would be quiet a waste to repeat the same code 118 times.

Comment: Well, to use target-action, you have to call `-addTarget...` one way or another. I'm not sure how else one would use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:-

Add this method to **ElementButton** class:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

[self addTarget:nil action:@selector(ownMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
```

**ownMethod**  which you want to  call with  UIControlEventTouchUpInside in any class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the method to the class or add the method individually to each one. Use a loop to go through all your buttons and use addTarget:selector:forEvent: to assign the method to each one. You can use a outlet collection which will give you an array to loop through, or you can just loop through all the subviews of the superview of these buttons (checking if the subview is of the right class).